# adding data to search results

Tags: php, sql, database

found an easier way around it

```
<html>
<form method="post" name="update" action="edit.php" />
Alliance Name :

<input type="text" name="term" />

Diplomacy :

<select name="dip">
       <option value="">Neutral</option>
       <option value="Hostile">Hostile</option>
       <option value="pending">Pending</option>
       <option value="friendly">Friendly</option>
       <option value="">Neutral</option>
      </select>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update" />
</form>

</html>
```

and

```
connection

$term = $_POST['term'];
$dip = $_POST['dip'];

$query = "UPDATE my_table SET dip = '$dip' WHERE alliance = '$term'";

if(mysql_query($query)){
echo "updated";}
else{
echo "fail";}
?>
```

all works great, thanks for all your advice.

I'm slowly getting there. you are all a great help and i respect you greatly

Comment: When you say `add`, do you mean change data in the database or add a completely new row?

Comment: what exectly you want to do in update statement.
as per query you are just updating 'dip' column with '$dip' variable where 'dip' column value is equal to '$dip' value.

means you are just updating certail records with the same value???

Comment: the column is already there with a NULL value, i want to insert the data to replace the NULL

Comment: the $dip column has the NULL value and this is where in need to put the data

Answer (score 2):

> the only thing it will not do is actually add the data to the database

That's because your sql:

```
UPDATE mordred13 SET  dip='$dip'  WHERE dip='$dip'
```

doesn't actually change anything (it's like saying "set the color of everything that's blue to blue"). If you're trying to update columns that are `NULL` (gleaned from your comments), you can do:

```
UPDATE mordred13 SET  dip='$dip'  WHERE dip IS NULL
```

A couple of important asides, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection and `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. Look into using an API that supports parameterized queries, such as mysqli or PDO.